# Json Assertion - Error Assertion failure message: Value expected to match regexp

Tags: json, jmeter

Doing REST API Testing using Jmeter. when I am Using JSON Path Tester in HTTP Response and provided JSON Path Expression as `$..name`. Getting following matches

```
Done,
Won't Do,
Duplicate,
Cannot Reproduce
```

[image]

But when I place the same JSON expression and Result in JSON Assertion, getting the error:-

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Value expected to match regexp '"Done","Won't Do","Duplicate","Cannot Reproduce"', but it did not match: '["Done","Won't Do","Duplicate","Cannot Reproduce"]'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To match multiple values**

1. Extract all the matching values from JSON Response using JSON Extractor
2. Use JSR223 Assertion with following code:

   ```
   int nameLength = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Name_matchNr"));

   String[] responseArray = new String[nameLength];
   for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
       responseArray[i] = vars.get("Name_"+(i+1));
   }

   boolean test1 = Arrays.asList(responseArray).contains("Done");
   boolean test2 = Arrays.asList(responseArray).contains("Won't Do");
   boolean test3 = Arrays.asList(responseArray).contains("Duplicate");
   boolean test4 = Arrays.asList(responseArray).contains("Cannot Reproduce");

   if (test1 == false) {
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Done not present in Response");
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
   }
   if (test2 == false) {
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Won't Do not present in Response");
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
   }
   if (test3 == false) {
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Duplicate not present in Response");
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
   }
   if (test4 == false) {
   AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Cannot Reproduce not present in Response");
   AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
   }
   ```

[image]

**To match single value**

1. Use JSON Extractor to extract the values
2. Use JSON Assertion to Assert the values. In `Expected Value` section enter any single value : `"Done/Won't Do/Duplicate/Cannot Reproduce"`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes That I am able to do - one single match. But trying to verify more than one.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what you're trying to achieve, consider the following [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) configuration:

[image]

Just in case "Expected Value" textual representation:

```
["Done","Won't Do","Duplicate","Cannot Reproduce"]
```

However be informed that this form of assertion will be fragile and sensitive to any JSON changes, i.e. if the order of matches will not be the same - the assertion will fail. So I would rather recommend using one of the approaches described in [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter/) article.